# Determine width and height in Fragment's onCreateView()

Tags: android, android-fragments

In the `onCreateView()` of my `Fragment` class I am creating and returning a `View` whose contents need to be dynamically created based on the actual screen width and height of the `Fragment`.

It would be most ideal if I were able to determine the width and height within `onCreateView()`. This is because when the `View` is constructed within `onCreateView()`, many child `View`s are added to it, and how the parent layout `View` organises those children into columns depending on available width and height (to create a kind of 'fluid' column container).

I tried seeing what `LayoutParams` are contained in the `ViewGroup` passed to `onCreateView()` but the width and height seem to be constants as opposed to specific widths and heights.

Would I be correct in believing that, at this stage in the layout phase (within the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()`), there is no width and height available? If that is the case, then what I suspect I need to do is build my container `View` in two phases: (1) add the children to it initially, and then (2) actually organise those child `View`s into columns within an override of a method that's called at a point when the width and height are known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct. In fragment's `onCreateView()` width and height are not available yet (both are 0). Doing it exactly like you said in 2 stages is not needed. I suppose you can do it in two ways:

1. Without custom view: You can use `ViewTreeObserver` in fragment to determine when width and height are calculated, then calculate size for child views and add them.
2. With custom view: You can build custom view as you mentioned and in `onDraw()` you can add child views. In `onDraw()` method is width and heigh already calculated.